# How can i restrict access to my angular site only from single url

Tags: angular, referer

I have an angular web app. I want to restrict access to my site from all other external sites except one.
How can i achieve this? Is there a way i can access the referar url of the external site and display my app accordingly if it is coming from the trusted site .

Answer (score 0):

This problem is more related to the hosting of your website, for instance your web server or reverse proxy configuration.

Indeed, the [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header) header can not be read from Angular, but only from the web server/reverse proxy when it receives the request to serve the Angular files.

We would need more details about your hosting to help you on the configuration :)